# MySQL - change connection to MysqlWorkBeanch

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have a server at Amazon with my Database and I usually acess by  hpMyadmin with no problem, but I hate that. I downloaded the MYSQL WorkBench but I can't connet to my server, anyway. I am always receiving the same message as follow:

```
Connecting to MySQL server ... Can't connect to MySQL server on  (10061)
```

Someone, did have the same problem or known how to do?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't work with amazon but some providers don't allow direct access to their databaseserver

Comment: I assume you use phpMyAdmin located on Amazon server?

Answer (score 0):

Most providers allow access to database only from they local network. Databases aren't visible from the internet. The reason - security.

Server with phpMyAdmin is located in their internal network so it have no problem with accessing to database, but your computer is on the outside and DB isn't visible for it, hence the connection error.

If you have `ssh`(or `vpn`) access to machine (but you probably don't) you can create tunnel and access your DB through it with workbench.

On the other hand, you should be able to upload your own web client, different than phpMyAdmin e.g http://mywebsql.net/